# How to programatically move Mail Items to MS Outlook from a directory folder?

Tags: c#, vba

I can use VBA or C# to complete this task.

Problem: I have 100+ mail items (`.msg`, unsent e-mails containing subject lines, To line recipients, and attachments) stored in a directory folder (ex: `C:\temp`).

How do I iterate through the mail items and send them to a folder in MS Outlook 2010?

I tried using the `FileSystemObject` in VBA, which I was able to iterate through the "files" in the directory. However, I couldn't cast the files to `MailItem` to move each to MS Outlook.

My attempt:

```
    Public Sub Move_MailItems_To_Outlook_From_Directory_Folder()
    Dim directoryPath       As String
    Dim directoryFolder     As Object
    Dim aFile               As File
    Dim fso                 As New FileSystemObject
    Dim outlookApp          As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim emailFolder         As Outlook.Folder

    directoryPath = "\\Client\F$\temp\"

    Set directoryFolder = fso.GetFolder(directoryPath)
    Set outlookApp = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    ' Iterate thru files and add to MS Outlook "Drafts" folder.
    For Each aFile In directoryFolder.Files

        ' !!!! "ERROR: One or more parameter values are not valid." !!!
        '
        ' I don't think VBA provides a means to cast a File object as a MailItem
        ' object, which is what I imagine the Items.Add method expects as a parameter
        ' value.
        outlookApp.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts).Items.Add aFile
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this need to be done programmatically - can you instead just drag the files into Outlook from the folder where they're stored?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Drag+Drop isn't practical in this instance. The Mail Items are created and stored on a network drive, so there's poor performance dragging files from the drive to the MS Outlook Drafts folder. Second drag+drop from the folder into the Drafts folder is limited to 7 Mail Items at a time. So doing this in code is my ideal solution, since it'll save the employee from dragging+dropping for several minutes each time this task needs doing. I'll test your below Cimperiali solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Cimperiali's answer here:
http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?287203-vb6-how-to-open-an-outlook-email-that-s-located-on-the-harddrive&highlight=email

```
Private OutApp As Outlook.Application

Private Function getMailMessage(ByVal FileName As String) As String

    Dim outMsg As Object
    Dim outDraftFolder As MAPIFolder
    If Dir$(FileName) = "" Then
        'nothing to read
        getMailMessage = "File " & FileName & " not found"
        Exit Function
    End If
    If OutApp Is Nothing Then
        Set OutApp = New Outlook.Application
    End If

    Dim outFold As Outlook.Folders
    'get Draft folder of outlook
    Set outDraftFolder = OutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts)
    'load message as draft - it may be something else than a mailitem...
    Set outMsg = OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(FileName)
    'check the type:
    Dim sText As String
    If TypeOf outMsg Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        With outMsg
            sText = "A mailItem:"
            sText = sText & vbCrLf & "sender =" & .SenderName
            sText = sText & vbCrLf & "Received = " & .ReceivedTime
            sText = sText & vbCrLf & "Created = " & .CreationTime
            sText = sText & vbCrLf & "subject = " & .Subject
            sText = sText & vbCrLf & "Body:" & vbCrLf
            sText = sText & vbCrLf & .Body
         End With
    ElseIf TypeOf outMsg Is Outlook.ContactItem Then

         With outMsg
            sText = "A ContactItem:"
            sText = sText & vbCrLf & "Created = " & .CreationTime
            sText = sText & vbCrLf & "subject = " & .Subject
            sText = sText & vbCrLf & "NickName=" & .NickName
            sText = sText & vbCrLf & "Email: " & .Email1Address
            sText = sText & vbCrLf & "Company Name: " & .CompanyName
            sText = sText & vbCrLf & "Profession: " & .Profession
            sText = sText & vbCrLf
            sText = sText & vbCrLf & "Body:" & vbCrLf
            sText = sText & vbCrLf & .Body
         End With
    ElseIf TypeOf outMsg Is Outlook.AppointmentItem Then

        With outMsg
            sText = "An AppointmentItem:"
            sText = sText & vbCrLf & "Created = " & .CreationTime
            sText = sText & vbCrLf & "subject = " & .Subject
            sText = sText & vbCrLf & "Conversation Topic=" & .ConversationTopic
            sText = sText & vbCrLf & "Importance: " & .Importance
            sText = sText & vbCrLf & "Duration: " & .Duration
            sText = sText & vbCrLf & "Last Modification time: " & .LastModificationTime
            sText = sText & vbCrLf
            sText = sText & vbCrLf & "Body:" & vbCrLf
            sText = sText & vbCrLf & .Body
        End With

    ElseIf TypeOf outMsg Is Outlook.MeetingItem Then
        Dim mx As Outlook.MeetingItem
        With mx
            sText = "A MeetingItem:"
            sText = sText & vbCrLf & "Created = " & .CreationTime
            sText = sText & vbCrLf & "subject = " & .Subject
            sText = sText & vbCrLf & "Conversation Topic=" & .ConversationTopic
            sText = sText & vbCrLf & "Importance: " & .Importance
            sText = sText & vbCrLf & "Expiry Time: " & .ExpiryTime
            sText = sText & vbCrLf & "Last Modification time: " & .LastModificationTime
            sText = sText & vbCrLf
            sText = sText & vbCrLf & "Body:" & vbCrLf
            sText = sText & vbCrLf & .Body
        End With
    Else
        sText = "You need to write a bit more of code..."
    End If
    getMailMessage = sText
    Set outMsg = Nothing
    Set outDraftFolder = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Perfect, Tim. The "OutApp.CreateItemFromTemplate" method is what I need. Thanks for sharing!